# SQL Job Running parallel in mssql

Tags: sql-server

I have two **databases** where i need to run the same job at same time. It gives me error of already used. Delay doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean "already used"? If they are 2 separate databases then the only contention will be between server resources, not database. There's far too little detail here to even begin to be able to help you. Have a look at the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page, and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53393491/edit) your question by adhering to the guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Two different databases but on the same sql server. I have created a job send mail when the user save records at the same time on same database as well different database.

Comment: Already used meaning. Already used by the same user.

Comment: Those aren't errors. Post the SQL you're running and the error; sample data is likely going to help here as well.